# jersey json generation

Tags: java, json

We trying to generate json from our web service. The format of our JSON is given below. We are using jersey for generating JSON.

```
[
        {
            "InfoList": {
                "name": "test",
                "slot": "2",
            },
            "Info": {
                "Id": "212",
                "name": "sdsdsd",
            },
            "abcInfoList": [
                {
                    "aname": "",
                    "slt": "1",
                },
                {
                {
                    "aname": "",
                    "slt": "1",
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "InfoList": {
                "name": "test",
                "slot": "2",
            },
            "Info": {
                "Id": "212",
                "name": "sdsdsd",
            },
            "abcInfoList": [
                {
                    "aname": "",
                    "slt": "1",
                },
                {
                {
                    "aname": "",
                    "slt": "1",
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "InfoList": {
                "name": "test",
                "slot": "2",
            },
            "Info": {
                "Id": "212",
                "name": "sdsdsd",
            },
            "abcInfoList": [
                {
                    "aname": "",
                    "slt": "1",
                },
                {
                {
                    "aname": "",
                    "slt": "1",
                }
            ],
        },
]
```

We have designed a class below for keeping the values for generating JSON

```
@XmlRootElement(name="JasonClass")
public class JsonClass {

    @XmlElement(name="InfoList")
    public Info getInfoList()
    {
        return this.info;
    }
    public void setInfoList(InfoList infoList)
    {
        this.infoList=infoList;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="Info")
    public Info getInfo()
    {
        return this.hostInformation;
    }
    public void setInfo(Info info)
    {
        this.info=info;
    }


    @XmlElement(name="abcInfoList")
    public Info getabcInfoList()
    {
        return this.abcInfoList;
    }
    public void setabcInfoList(AbcInfoList abcInfoList)
    {
        this.abcInfoListt=abcInfoList;
    }
}

And we are returning array of JsonClass for JSON. 

    @GET
    @Path("/service")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public JsonClass[] getJsonList() {
        JsonClass[] jsonList = new JsonClass[count];
        //code for fliing array
        //code for fliing array
        return jsonList;
    }
```

And it is generating as given below

```
{ 
"JasonClass":[
        {
            "InfoList": {
            "name": "test",
            "slot": "2",
            },
            "Info": {
            "Id": "212",
            "name": "sdsdsd",
            },
            "abcInfoList": [
            {
                "aname": "",
                "slt": "1",
            },
            {
            {
                "aname": "",
                "slt": "1",
            }
            ],
        },
        {
            "InfoList": {
            "name": "test",
            "slot": "2",
            },
            "Info": {
            "Id": "212",
            "name": "sdsdsd",
            },
            "abcInfoList": [
            {
                "aname": "",
                "slt": "1",
            },
            {
            {
                "aname": "",
                "slt": "1",
            }
            ],
        },
        {
            "InfoList": {
            "name": "test",
            "slot": "2",
            },
            "Info": {
            "Id": "212",
            "name": "sdsdsd",
            },
            "abcInfoList": [
            {
                "aname": "",
                "slt": "1",
            },
            {
            {
                "aname": "",
                "slt": "1",
            }
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

But we dont want the followng in the JSON. We need only the array []. As give above (int he first json).

```
{ 
"JasonClass":
}
```

Comment: What if you remove the @xmlRootelement? Not sure if this is allowed tho

Comment: Xml Documents require a root node, you're basically here creating an xml document and then converting it to json.

Answer (score 0):

I would just skip the annotations and let a good JSON provider handle the conversion. As @Rob suggests, I think the problem is the `@XmlRootElement` annotation. I usually only define simple POJOs (but without setters and getters),

```
public class Info {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

Then, if you want to return a list of `Info` you would just return a `List<Info>` from your Jersey resource. The name of the class is omitted by default. I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you are using Jersey for JSON generation - as far as I know, Jersey in itself does not convert to/from JSON, you need an extension for that. I am using Jackson, which integrates well with Jersey (it only needs to be on the classpath, no extra configuration required).